# How do I set descriptions to each checkbox option

Tags: forms

Is there a way to set descriptions to each checkbox option? What I would like is for Option #1 to display and then directly below it a description for it, then Option #2 along with its description.
I have:

```
 $form['field_options'] = array(
                    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
                    '#options' => array(
                        0 => t('Option #1'),
                        1 => t('Option #2')),
                    '#title' => t('Select Options'),
                    '#description' => t('Entering a description here will display below the last item in the array'),
                    '#default_value' => array(0)
            );
```

Also, for some reason `$form_state['values']['field_options']` in function `hook_node_submit()` shows

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
)
```

shouldnt it show what the states of the checkboxes are like this?:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
function MYMODULE_process_checkbox_descriptions($element) {
foreach (element_children($element['#options']) as $key) {
    if (!empty($element['#checkbox_descriptions'][$key])) {
        $element[$key]= array(
            '#type' => 'checkbox',
            '#title' => $element['#options'][$key],
            '#description' => $element['#checkbox_descriptions'][$key]
            ) ;
    }
}
return $element;
}
```

And

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter($form, &$form_state,$form_id) {
  $form['field_options'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => array(
            1 => t('Option #1'),
            2 => t('Option #2')),
    '#checkbox_descriptions' => array(
            1=> t('Description #1'),
            2=> t('Description #2')),
    '#title' => t('Select Options'),
    '#description' => t('Entering a description here will display below the last item in the array'),
    '#default_value' => array(1),
    '#process' => array('MYMODULE_process_checkbox_descriptions'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Worked nicely!! thanks @Clive and @Marcel !

Comment: This works for me! THX!

Comment: Don't you think this way will not pass the Drupal Form security measurements? At least if you're trying to alter existing fields.

Answer (score 1):

The #title will be displayed as a description next to the checkbox, description below it if you use single checkboxes in a for-loop.

You need to change it a bit:

```
$options = array('Option 1' => t('Description1'), 'Option2' => t('Description 2');
$i = 1;
foreach ($options as $title => $description) {
    $form['field_options']['option_' . $i]= array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => $title,
      '#description' => $description,
      '#default_value' => 0,
    );
  $i++;
}
```

Set the value with #default_value = 0; (not an array).

About the 0 value in the array: From [drupal.org Form API about checkboxes](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#checkboxes):
Description: Format a set of checkboxes. #options is an associative array, where the key is the #return_value of the checkbox and the value is displayed. The #options array cannot have a 0 key, as it would not be possible to discern checked and unchecked states.

Comment: That will give you exactly one checkbox every time...

Comment: Ah i see there is a problem with this one, forgot to iterate he fieldname, i will update some (it will be overwriting).

Comment: That's definitely one way to do it, but it's possible to override the default behaviour. I've chucked some code in an answer, something similar to that should work

Answer (score 1):

The individual checkboxes are extracted in [`form_process_checkboxes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_checkboxes/7), so I guess something like this would work (un-tested):

```
function MYMODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $options = array(1 => t('Option #1'), 2 => t('Option #2'));

  // Keyed the same as $options
  $descs = array(1 => t('Desc #1'), 2 => t('Desc #2'));

  $form['field_options'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $options
    '#title' => t('Select Options'),
    '#description' => t('Entering a description here will display below the last item in the array'),
    '#default_value' => array(1),
    '#checkbox_descriptions' => $descriptions,
    '#process' => array('MYMODULE_process_checkbox_descriptions'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function MYMODULE_process_checkbox_descriptions($element) {
  foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
    if (!empty($element['#checkbox_descriptions'][$element[$key]['#return_value']])) {
      $element[$key]['#description'] = $element['#checkbox_descriptions'][$element[$key]['#return_value']];
    }
  }

  return $element;
}
```

Comment: I modded your code a little, for the most part it works. But now the check boxes are gone and only  `$form['field_options']['#description]` is showing. I suppose there is an error when rendering?

`function MYMODULE_process_checkbox_descriptions($element) { foreach (element_children($element['#options']) as $key) {
if (!empty($element['#checkbox_descriptions'][$key])) {
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . $element['#options'][$key] . ' will get ' . $element['#checkbox_descriptions'][$key] .'<br></pre>');
$element['#options'][$key]['#description'] = $element['#checkbox_descriptions'][$key];
}
}`

Answer (score 1):

I came across this and the Accepted answer doesn't seem correct. It may work, but there is a much simpler approach. To set an individual `#description` per checkbox, you'll want to add a new item(s) to the `$form` array, using the array key you want to set the description for.

So given the original example where the array keys are `0` and `1`...

```
$form['field_options'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => array(
    0 => t('Option #1'),
    1 => t('Option #2')),
  '#title' => t('Select Options'),
  '#description' => t('Entering a description here will display below the last item in the array'),
  '#default_value' => array(0),
);
```

You will want to add the following to your `$form` array to set a description for each checkbox...

```
$form['field_options'][0]['#description'] = 'Custom description for option one (array key 0)';
$form['field_options'][1]['#description'] = 'Custom description for option two (array key 1)';
```

Comment: So much simpler and easier than the accepted solution, thanks!