# How do I save the values for a custom fieldset?

Tags: forms, organic-groups

Relating to my question ([here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/113041/how-do-i-set-descriptions-to-each-checkbox-option)). I made a custom field set to toggle organic group visibility. The UI looks and functions as it should, meaning when I have both my fieldset and `$form['group_access']` fieldset showing, I can toggle settings from either and the changes show correctly in both. When I hide `$form['group_access']` with `$form['group_access']['#access']=FALSE;` the values do not appear to get written to the database when I hit save. Shouldn't I be able to set `$form['group_access']['und']['#entity']->group_access['und'][0]['value']` to the values in my custom fieldset? Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be in `hook_form_alter` add a custom validate handler:

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_validate_handler';
```

then you should be able to do (double check that with debug(), print_r() or devel):

```
function my_custom_validate_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {

    $form_state['values']['group_access']['und'][0]['value'] = 1;

}
```

Another way would be to set a '#default_value' and it should be something like that:

```
$form['group_access']['und'][0]['default']['#default_value'] = 1
```

Hope that helps!